# Keep indents on empty lines C# in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, formatting, resharper, indentation

There is an options in intellij that allows you to keep indents on empty lines. After ReSharper formatting it removes all my spaces in blank lines within method. How can I configure ReSharper/Visual Studio to keep indents within method only?

[image]

Comment: Hey, have you tried using TAB keys for indenting instead of using spaces? I found that TAB characters are preserved, but lines filled with whitespaces are removed. Maybe the "workaround" is to change the settings in `Options > Text Editor > C# > Tabs > Tab` to `Keep tabs` instead of `Insert spaces`. Would that be feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, not a lot of people cared about keeping the indents in empty lines.

[That feature request was closed without much fanfare.](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/5570042-implement-proper-indent-reindent-command)

Either that, or I didn't see anyone voting for such feature to be in Visual Studio IDE.